# True or False questions

Tags: exam

I want to make an test/exam with only true or false questions and I want to make a page where the students could mark only T or F, without the questions in it. And I want it to show the answers when I need.

Any help?

Comment: Generally, putting answers on separate sheets is done for automatic grading machines.  If you intend to reuse the question sheet, be warned that people often write on them anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A tricky way: You set a command `\status` storing the status (answer sheet or answer key) of the document.

If you want to hide the answer keys, set it to `white`. Set it to `black` otherwise.

*You are in the answer key:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\status{black}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\status}{white}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} Foo bar
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{F}\quad} Dummy text
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{F}\quad} Hello world
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} Loren lipsum
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} There is something in the sky.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*You are in the answer sheet:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\status{black}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\status}{white}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} Foo bar
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{F}\quad} Dummy text
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{F}\quad} Hello world
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} Loren lipsum
    \item \underline{\quad\textcolor{\status}{T}\quad} There is something in the sky.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can define a new command based on `\item` to make this easier.

Comment: You could also use `\pdfcomment[opacity=\status]{T/F}` (pdfcomment package) in case the paper isn't white..